# Why sql is converted into prepared statement style execution internally in performing mysql DB operation using go lang

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

Using "database/sql" or gorm , any query (select/update) which I am executing on MYSQL DB is converted internally into a prepared statement. There are multiple message exchanges happening.

1. Prepare Statement [client -> DB]
2. DB Response       [ DB -> client]
3. Execute Statement [Client -> DB ]
4. Execute Statement Response [ DB-> Client]
5. Close Statement   [client->DB ]

It will take at least 3 RTTs to complete the transaction.

Is there any ways to reduce the number of message exchange using sending a direct query. It should be possible to do it in 1RTT.
But Even sttment.Query(text) is internally converted into prepared statement format.

Comment: Don't know about mysql but in postgres there's no other way to pass paramaters to the db server than with prepared statements. Only queries that don't take arguments are sent to the server as such.

Comment: @mkopriva any reference for this? I would like also to know the reasoning behind this.

Comment: [simple query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-flow.html#id-1.10.5.7.4) and [extended query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY)